# Bootstrap Material Design bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap with material design from http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/ and I'm having problems with pagination, here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>IKEA Industry | Main Gate Self Service</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- BootStrap Table -->
    <link href="../css/boostrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Material Design Ripples -->
    <link href="../css/ripples.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Material Design Ripples -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-material-design.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap Material Datepicker -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Style -->
    <link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">
    #ikeagateForm .availabilityContainer .form-control-feedback {
        right: 15px;
    }
  </style>
    </head>

<body>
<div>
       <ul class="pagination">
         <li class="disabled"><a href="javascript:void(0)">«</a></li>
         <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">2<div class="ripple-container"></div></a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">3<div class="ripple-container"></div></a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">4<div class="ripple-container"></div></a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">5<div class="ripple-container"></div></a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">»<div class="ripple-container"></div></a></li>
       </ul>
</div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tether.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap material design JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/material.js"></script>

    <!-- material design ripples JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ripples.js"></script>

    <!-- BootStrap Validator -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datepicker Moment -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

    <!-- BootStrap Datepicker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <!-- BootStrap Table -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() 
  {
      $(function() 
      {
          $.material.init();
      });
  });    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I've some more CSS and JS loaded because I removed this from the main site to check if it was some incompatibility with something but also here I get this result:

[Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjyBp.jpg)

What am I missing?

PS: I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.3

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your CSS isnt loading correctly, is the path correct?

Comment: Yes the path is correct. And the css is loading for modals etc etc so its only something related to UL tag maybe I will try with BS3

Comment: Might use a different Syntax than Bootstrap 3

Comment: You haven't included popper.min.js files which is necessary for BS4. You haven't included bootstrap.min.js script either...